# How to apply impulse to all sprites of a group with a delay between each in iOS SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, skspritenode

I am making a brick breaker style game in Xcode for iOS. There is no paddle and balls are all launched from the same location (determined by where the first ball falls from the last level). There are a varying number of balls launched each time based on the number of balls the player has created. Each game starts with one ball but the user collects more in playing. When applying an impulse to the ball sprites I can only either move one sprite or all ball sprites at once. How do I move the ball sprites with a delay between each sprites launch?

Below I will go over what I have tried already. Thank you in advance for any help!

So far I have tried a couple of things. First I was trying to create all ball sprites prior to allowing the user to launch and having all ball sprites at the same location. Then I enumerated over them and tried to launch them with a delay there. However this simply launched all balls simultaneously after the delay, not each individually.

```
gameWorldNode.enumerateChildNodes(withName: BallCategoryName) {
     node, stop in
     let ball = node as! SKSpriteNode
     ball.move(toParent: gameWorldNode)
                    
     //Calculate Vector
     var dx = CGFloat(touchLocation.x - ball.position.x)
     var dy = CGFloat(touchLocation.y - ball.position.y)
                    
     //Calculate Magnitude
     let magnitude = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
                    
     dx /= magnitude
     dy /= magnitude
                    
     //Create Vector
     let vector = CGVector(dx: 30.0 * dx, dy: 30.0 * dy)
                    
     let secondsToDelay = 0.25
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + secondsToDelay){       
          //Apply impulse
           ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(vector)
                
     }
```

}

Secondly, It occurred to me that it would probably be better for game performance if I didn't create the ball sprite until right before the impulse is applied, after the previous ball is launched. So I tried the following code. However, while I think I may be on the right path now, the newly created ball sprites don't launch. They get created but for some reason they don't apply the impulse.

```
let ball = gameWorldNode.childNode(withName: BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
ball.move(toParent: gameWorldNode)

//Calculate Vector
var dx = CGFloat(touchLocation.x - ball.position.x)
var dy = CGFloat(touchLocation.y - ball.position.y)

//Calculate Magnitude
let magnitude = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

dx /= magnitude
dy /= magnitude

//Create Vector
let vector = CGVector(dx: 30.0 * dx, dy: 30.0 * dy)

ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(vector)

var i = 1
while (i != ballsAvailabe) {
    //Create new ball sprite
    let nextBall: SKSpriteNode = Ball()
    nextBall.position = CGPoint(x: locationX, y: locationY)
    gameWorldNode.addChild(nextBall)

    let secondsToDelay = 0.1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + secondsToDelay) {
        //Apply impulse to ball
        nextBall.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(vector)
    }
    //Update i
    i += 1
}
```

I have also tried to add the sprites to an array and iterate over the array. However, this simply launches each ball at once still.

```
for _ in 0..<ballsAvailabe {
    //Create new ball sprite
    let ball: SKSpriteNode = Ball()
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: locationX, y: locationY)
    ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = nextBallCategory
    ball.color = nextBallInPlay
    ball.colorBlendFactor = 1
    ball.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BottomCategory | AddABallCategory | RedBlockCategory | BlueBlockCategory | OrangeBlockCategory | PurpleBlockCategory | GreenBlockCategory | CyanBlockCategory
    ballSprites.append(ball)
    gameWorldNode.addChild(ball)
}
                
  for sprite in ballSprites {
       let secondsToDelay = 0.3
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + secondsToDelay)      {
            sprite.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(vector)
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Following Johns comment below, I have added code to my second attempt to ensure the physics bodies are created properly. Sorry for all the variables in the code they are just global variables I have created and keep in its own file to ensure I am keeping values consistent throughout the code. This works better. When the user only has one ball it works perfectly. However, when the user has collected more balls to launch it will sometimes launch perfectly with the delay to the expected location. Other times it will launch only the first ball. Other times it will launch to an unexpected location.

Heres the updated code:

```
//Grab existing ball object
 let ball = gameWorldNode.childNode(withName: BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
                
//Assign to game world node
ball.move(toParent: gameWorldNode)
                
//Apply ball properties
ball.color = nextBallInPlay
ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width / 2)
ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = RedBallCategory
ball.name = BallCategoryName
ball.colorBlendFactor = 1
ball.physicsBody?.pinned = false
ball.physicsBody?.mass = ballMass
ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = ballGravity
ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = ballRotation
ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = ballDynamic
ball.zPosition = ballZPos
ball.physicsBody?.friction = ballFriction
ball.physicsBody?.restitution = ballRestitution
ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = ballLinearDaming
ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = ballAngularDamping
                 
//Stop more launches and accidently using power ups
isFingerOnScreen = true
canBallBeLaunched = false
canUsePowerUps = false
                
//Ensure physics world speed is accurate
physicsWorld.speed = 1
                
//Launching location
var dx = CGFloat(touchLocation.x - locationX)
var dy = CGFloat(touchLocation.y - locationY)
                
//Calculate Magnitude
let magnitude = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
                
dx /= magnitude
dy /= magnitude
                
//Create Vector
let vector = CGVector(dx: 30.0 * dx, dy: 30.0 * dy)
                
//Apply impule to first ball
ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(vector)

//loop to create x number of balls based on what the user has collected
var i = 1
while (i != ballsAvailabe) {
    //Create new ball sprite
    let nextBall: SKSpriteNode = Ball()
    nextBall.position = CGPoint(x: locationX, y: locationY)
    gameWorldNode.addChild(nextBall)
                    
    //Ball properties
    nextBall.color = nextBallInPlay
    nextBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width / 2)
    nextBall.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = RedBallCategory
    nextBall.name = BallCategoryName
    nextBall.colorBlendFactor = 1
    nextBall.physicsBody?.pinned = false
    nextBall.physicsBody?.mass = ballMass
    nextBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = ballGravity
    nextBall.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = ballRotation
    nextBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = ballDynamic
    nextBall.zPosition = ballZPos
    nextBall.physicsBody?.friction = ballFriction
    nextBall.physicsBody?.restitution = ballRestitution
    nextBall.physicsBody?.linearDamping = ballLinearDaming
    nextBall.physicsBody?.angularDamping = ballAngularDamping

    //Delay between each ball
    let secondsToDelay = 0.1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + secondsToDelay) {
         //Apply impulse to ball
         nextBall.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(vector)
    }
    //Update i
    i += 1
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd attempt, does Ball() have its physicsbody set up correctly? (I guess the same way as BallCategoryName node)

Comment: John, I just double checked and I believe you are correct. I created the physics bodies and now it kinda works.It works great before the user collects more balls to launch. Then when trying to launch more than one ball it will sometimes work perfectly, other times it will launch only the first or launch to a completely random location. This is my first project and I believe in my attempt to keep everything organized I made the code more complex and created a ton of variables to keep track of. I taught myself all of this from tutorials so the code organization is probably far from ideal.